# Jmeter tests freeze at o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTP TrustAll Socket Factory

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, software-quality

I am executing performance tests using jmeter+docker setup. When I try to run the tests after docker set up, It starts execution but freezes at
`INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTP TrustAll Socket Factory`
This is before starting the first test.

If I kill the process and restart the execution, It will move from above step, execute first thread group and freeze again on second thread group.

FYI - I have added trust certificates and invoking them using command line
`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path of certificates`
`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password`

Can anyone please help me figuring out what am I missing here ? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your question doesn't provide sufficient level of details.

Try the following:

0. First of all try reproducing the issue without Docker virtualization, if it cannot be reproduced on the host machine - double check your docker setup, inspect docker logs, container logs and so on.

If it can be reproduced without Docker:

1. [Increase JMeter's logging level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG
2. Add the next line to **system.properties** file

   ```
   javax.net.debug=all
   ```

   it will enable [debug output for SSL/TLS connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)
3. When JMeter "freezes" next time take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump)

This way you will know at which line of code JMeter gets stuck so you will know the exact reason.